# In ASP.NET, how do I convert ~/Application/Page.aspx to http://localhost:45/MyApp/Application/Page.aspx

Tags: asp.net

Basically I want to convert a virtual path to an absolute path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
/// <summary>
/// Return full path of the IIS application
/// </summary>
public string FullyQualifiedApplicationPath
{
    get
    {
        //Getting the current context of HTTP request
        var context = HttpContext.Current;

        //Checking the current context content
        if (context == null) return null;

        //Formatting the fully qualified website url/name
        var appPath = string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}{3}",
                                    context.Request.Url.Scheme,
                                    context.Request.Url.Host,
                                    context.Request.Url.Port == 80
                                        ? string.Empty
                                        : ":" + context.Request.Url.Port,
                                    context.Request.ApplicationPath);

        if (!appPath.EndsWith("/"))
            appPath += "/";

        return appPath;
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm with a slight modification:  private static string ToAbsolute(string AppRelative)
 {
  HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
  return string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}{3}",
          context.Request.Url.Scheme,
          context.Request.Url.Host,
          context.Request.Url.Port == 80
           ? string.Empty
           : ":" + context.Request.Url.Port,
          VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(AppRelative));
 }